# expression cant be called as a function : error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, return

I am facing a compile time error here.

I tried to find solution to the error but cant reach a conclusion.

It says "expression cant be called as a function" when I am trying to return value using parenthesis in a user defined function.

My code is:

```cpp
template <class t1>
t1 sum(t1 a, t1 b)
{
    if (a != b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    else
    {
        return 3(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't tag unrelated languages.  This is not `C` code.

Comment: What is `3(a+b)` supposed to be doing? `3` is not a function, so you can't call it like one

Comment: `3(a+b)` appears to be some mathematical notation, not anything that would be recognized as C++ code.  Did you mean `3*(a+b)`?

Comment: You have to use a mathematical operator to multiply 3 by (a+b), otherwise it thinks 3 is a function.

Comment: `return 3 * (a+b);` perhaps?

Comment: `return 3(a+b);` -- C++ syntax is not schoolbook math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3(a+b)` means nothing for a C++ compiler. If you are trying to multiply, use `3*(a+b)`. If `3` is a function, change its name, you can't use a number as a function name.